# Extjs4 - What is the equivalent to ExtJs3's panel 'findByType' method?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

What is the equivalent to the below in Extjs4?

```
panel.findByType('portlet');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
panel.query('portlet')
```

...and more text here so I can submit the answer...